# OpenCV - How to get only first frame and skip other frames when servo function is called

Tags: python, opencv

my project I'm working on is face recognition. The face recognition bit works fine. However when the face is recognised, and the servo opens the door and closes after seconds. Servo keeps opening the door when there is no one in front of the camera.It stops after 5-10 times opening and closing the door. First I thought sleep would be the solution, but this did not work, I tried without the for loop as well, but still, the servo keeps opening. I think OpenCV captures frames the few seconds I'm standing in front of the camera. Is there any way I can only open the door when there is a person (recognised face) in front of the camera.I'm using the ip camera

Thanks

```
import cv2
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import numpy as np
import threading 
class main:

    def servo(self):
        print ("door open")
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
        pwm=GPIO.PWM(11,50)
        pwm.start(8)
        time.sleep(5.20)
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(3)

    def face(self):
        recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
        recognizer.read('trainner/trainner.yml')
        cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
        faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        num = 1
        while True:
            ret, frame =cam.read()
            gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2,5)
            for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(225,0,0),2)
                Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                if(conf >= 50):
                    if(Id==1):
                        Id="Person 1"
                    elif(Id==2):
                        Id="Person 2"#
                else:
                    Id="Unknown"
                cv2.putText(frame,str(Id), (x, y+h), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.imshow('im',frame) 
                if cv2.waitKey(1) ==ord('q'):
                    break
        cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

app = main()
app.face()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is to track the face till it gets out of the frame, when you first detect the face you call your function and you should keep the door open till the face isn't tracked anymore (got out of the frame)